# How to access join table attributes (has_many :through) from association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-many-through

I'm trying to create records list with the attributes of the associated records. Get `Task` `goal` Attribute inherit \ replace `Power` - `goal` Attribute

if we have:

`@tasks = user.tasks`

when we render the view

`<%= render @tasks %>`

Everything is fine, we can just use `<%= task.goal %>` in the partial and all working, but if we have `user.super_tasks` how to override goal in the partial?

The first thing that comes to mind is to make in the `_task.htm.erbl`

`<%= goal = if @super_tasks then task.powers.find_by(user_id: current_user).goal else task.goal end %>`

It's kind of make it, but this ok if you have 3 records, with 15 it will make 15 request to db to find the join table each time.

Just added the tables to make it more clear:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tasks
   has_many :powers
   has_many :super_tasks , through: :powers, source: :task
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :powers
end

class Power < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :tasks 
end
```

But if user have power they have more responsibilities, its not the first time that I stuck on that problem, for sure there is other way to make this work without calling the db each time, as it sadly common problem.

Comment: See [Active Record Query Interface - Joining Tables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) and [Active Record Query Interface - Eager-loading Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

Comment: Even if you `join `or `Eager-loading` you will need to iterate through all the records, for example:

     <% task.powers.each do |pw| %>
         <% if pw.user_id == current_user.id %> 
              <%= pw.goal %>
         <% end %>
      <% end %>
 it will work, but that's not the clean way that I looked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok maybe it not the best solution, but it works and answers the question:

```
tasks = user.tasks.order(:id)
power_tasks = user.powers.order(:task_id)

tasks.each_with_index do |task,i|
    task.goal = power_tasks[i].goal 
end
```

The weak point if this code is, if we say there is no `task_id` to order \ adjust the `power` or if the number `power_tasks` does not match the tasks.
But for my case it worked perfectly.

If you want to added other param, that not exist on normal `Task`, but exist on `Power` table and you want to added it to `tasks` also, then in the model we can:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :cookies

task.cookies = power_tasks[i].cookies
```